# How to compare 2 different hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, compare

I have 2 Strings that I convert to HashMaps, the first one is an input the user gives to the application. The second one is an Array that contains a lot of words.

I need to compare both HashMaps to check if the input can be reorganize to match one of the words of the Array. There's no need to use every single char the user input to the system, there can be some leftover char from the first HashMap, but I need to be sure they can match one of the words from the Array (the second HashMap).

Here's how I create the first HashMap:

```
String normalizedInputWord = normalizeString(inputWord);

Map<Character, Integer> countDuplicateMapInput = new HashMap<>();

char[] charInputArray = normalizedInputWord.toCharArray();

for (char c: charInputArray) {
    if (countDuplicateMapInput.containsKey(c)) {
        countDuplicateMapInput.put(c, countDuplicateMapInput.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        countDuplicateMapInput.put(c, 1);
    }
}
```

This is the second one:

```
Map<Character, Integer> countDuplicateMapArray = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    // Calls a function to normalize each String of the wordArray Array
    String normalizedWordArray = normalizeString(wordArray[i]);

    char[] charWordArray = normalizedWordArray.toCharArray();

    for (char c : charWordArray) {
        if (countDuplicateMapArray.containsKey(c)) {
            countDuplicateMapArray.put(c, countDuplicateMapArray.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
            countDuplicateMapArray.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I compare these 2 structures and get a "true" response to the example below?

Example:
The input is "unstoppable" and the countDuplicateMapInput will have:

```
{
key: "p", value: 2;
key: "a", value: 1;
key: "b", value: 1;
key: "s", value: 1;
key: "t", value: 1;
key: "u", value: 1;
key: "e", value: 1;
key: "l", value: 1;
key: "n", value: 1;
key: "o", value: 1;
}
```

and there's the word "stop" in my Array that will populate the countDuplicateMapArray this way:

```
{
key: "p", value: 1;
key: "t", value: 1;
key: "s", value: 1;
key: "o", value: 1;
}
```

Comment: 70% of your question is meaningless, since it doesn't matter at all *how* you build the two maps. Now given the 2 example HashMaps at the end of the question, what is it again you're asking? If one of them is a superset of the other, I believe? Please **edit** the question, get rid of irrelevant stuff, and otherwise clarify what you need to determine.

Comment: I just tried to put all the information that someone could've need to think on the best solution. I need a solution that implements whatever values I have in the first HashMap, they need to contain the values of the second HashMap. If the second HashMap has a key "a", value 3; the first HashMap needs at least one key "a", value 3 (or more).

Comment: So I was right? You just need to know if the first map is a superset of the second map.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I didn't understand what did you mean with superset, I'm kinda new with programing and I don't understand some expressions.

Comment: No it's not strictly a superset. That is because the values for matching keys need to be greater than or equal to. For a strict superset the values would have to be equal.

Comment: @sprinter You're mistaken, the very definition of [superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) is "equal or greater".

Comment: @MichaelRodrigues [Superset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) is a *math* term, not a *programming* term.

Comment: @Andreas the map (1->3) is not considered a superset of the map (1->2) because the values for the key 1 are not equal. In OPs case that pair of sets should pass the test.

Comment: @sprinter `[A=3, B=3, C=1]` is a superset of `[A=2, C=1]`, because it has at least 2 A's and 1 C. It has more letters than that, i.e. an extra A and 3 B's, which is the *super* part (more allowed). --- Note that a `Map` is not a "set", so when we say super*set*, we're talking about the total collection of *letter* the `Map<Character, Integer>` represents, we're not talking about e.g. the `keySet` or the `entrySet`.

Comment: @Andreas sorry that really makes no sense at all. We'll have to agree to disagree on the meaning of superset with respect to maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand your requirements but I think you want a test that checks if all keys in the second map have values in the first map that are greater than or equal to the second map's value.

If that's correct then:

```
countDuplicateMapArray.entrySet().stream()
     .allMatch(e -> countDuplicateMapInput.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), 0) >= e.getValue())
```

Also note that you can use `merge` to simplify your code to create the maps:

```
countDuplicateMapInput.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Or even better would be create the map directly from the inputs:

```
Map<Integer,Long> characterCounts = normalizeString(inputWord).chars().boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
```

This uses `Integer` rather than `Character` to represent the characters (by zero extending the char) but it shouldn't make any difference for you given you are just using them in a predicate.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you!